# Powershell: Import-CSV - How to select specific cells (ie: A5, A10. A15)

Tags: powershell, csv, import, invoke-webrequest, export-csv

I've created a script using invoke-webrequest and filtered the information I need and exported the data to a CSV file, The data is formatted into list view and therefore the data extracted is placed onto a new row down the CSV file (which suits my needs quite fine).

Now I've imported that CSV back into Powershell and I want to select certain cells of information from it. Is there a way of selecting particular cells into a variable that I can use else where in my script.

Much appreciated, 
Cheers,
For example
Setting $ie1 to hold data from A5
Setting $ie2 to hold data from A10
Setting $ie3 to hold data from A15

Comment: If you say _"The data is formatted into list view"_, then to me that sounds like it is no longer a CSV to work with, instead, a series of lines in a text file. Next you talk about column names as in Excel (`A10`, `A15`).. Without showing **ANY** of all this, there is no way we can help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can import the CSV into an array: `$array = @(Import-CSV "temp.csv")`, then address individual cells by row and column number.

The address scheme column letter/row number is specific to spreadsheet programs, but you can write a translation function if you find it useful.

Answer based on STGdb's comment [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004302/using-powershell-to-import-data-properly-into-an-array)